# How to use a anonymous C++ union with anonymous structs

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I need help with the syntax to access a union within a struct as shown below.  The compiler complains that I need must name the 'innerStruct' definition below as opposed to having an anonymous inner struct.  Could someone please explain the rules and how I can initialize the constructor fields and name the bit field elements.  I have a **[live coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c888a828ee7255a6)** to show the code.

Unfortunately the code does not compile as it indicates the following error:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In constructor 'Foo::Foo(uint8_t, uint8_t)':
main.cpp:38:11: error: class 'Foo' does not have any field named 'asUint8'
         , asUint8(aBitFields)
           ^
main.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Foo&)':
main.cpp:54:83: error: 'const struct Foo' has no member named 'innerStruct'
             << "], mA[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mA
                                                                                   ^
main.cpp:55:83: error: 'const struct Foo' has no member named 'innerStruct'
             << "], mB[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mB
                                                                                   ^
main.cpp:56:83: error: 'const struct Foo' has no member named 'innerStruct'
             << "], mC[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mC
                                                                                   ^
main.cpp:57:83: error: 'const struct Foo' has no member named 'innerStruct'
             << "], mD[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mD
                                                                                   ^

struct Foo {
    // fields
    uint8_t mType;
    union innerUnion_t {
        struct innerStruct_t {
            uint8_t mA : 2;
            uint8_t mB : 1;
            uint8_t mC : 2;
            uint8_t mD : 3;
        } innerStruct;
        uint8_t asUint8;
    } innerUnion;

    // constructor
    explicit Foo() = default;

    // constructor
    explicit Foo(
        const uint8_t aType,
        const uint8_t aBitFields)
        : mType(aType)
        , asUint8(aBitFields)
    {}

    /**
     * Stream insert operator<p>
     *
     * @param os     [in,out] output stream
     * @param rhs    [in] Foo to send to the output
     *               stream.
     *
     * @return a reference to the updated stream
     */
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(
        std::ostream& os, const Foo& rhs) {
        os  << "Foo"
            << ": type[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.mType
            << "], mA[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mA
            << "], mB[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mB
            << "], mC[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mC
            << "], mD[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mD
            << "]";
        return os;
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

Note: following the suggested answer with a slight change to the struct definition, I also have an additional question about what the syntax should be to initialize or refer to the bit fields mA -> mD, I tried in the constructor using the following syntax but it doesn't compile either.  I tried to name the innerUnion and explictly refer to its named nested struct as **innerUnion.innerStruct.mA(1)** - see **[second live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c70000fb425acd86)**

It gives the following error:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'Foo::Foo(uint8_t, uint8_t)':
main.cpp:39:21: error: expected '(' before '.' token
         , innerUnion.innerStruct.mA(1)
                     ^
main.cpp:39:21: error: expected '{' before '.' token
```

Comment: note: your field names suggest you intend to use *union aliasing*. This is undefined behaviour in Standard C++; only the most recently-written union member may be read.  Also the order and spacing of of bitfields is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove some words in your code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    for (auto& el : vec)
    {
        os << el << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

struct Foo {
    // fields
    uint8_t mType;
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t mA : 2;
            uint8_t mB : 1;
            uint8_t mC : 2;
            uint8_t mD : 3;
        } innerStruct;
        uint8_t asUint8;
    };

    // constructor
    explicit Foo() = default;

    // constructor
    explicit Foo(
        const uint8_t aType,
        const uint8_t aBitFields)
        : mType(aType)
        , asUint8(aBitFields)
    {}

    /**
     * Stream insert operator<p>
     *
     * @param os     [in,out] output stream
     * @param rhs    [in] Foo to send to the output
     *               stream.
     *
     * @return a reference to the updated stream
     */
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(
        std::ostream& os, const Foo& rhs) {
        os  << "Foo"
            << ": type[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.mType
            << "], mA[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mA
            << "], mB[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mB
            << "], mC[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mC
            << "], mD[0x" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << rhs.innerStruct.mD
            << "]";
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = {
        "Hello", "from", "GCC", __VERSION__, "!"
    };
    std::cout << words << std::endl;

    auto pFoo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
    std::cout << *pFoo << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks but also I may not have asked this but in the constructor how can I explicitly initialize the named bit fields - as you can see I initialize the asUnit9 field which is synonymous with all the combined bit fields.

Comment: @johnco3: `Foo::Foo() : innerStruct.mA(3) {}`

Comment: I tried that in the header file as follows but it does not compile http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca08f988c49fe343 - I did manage to initialize it as follows though http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0417323b5ee50539

Comment: I believe that you are correct in your last piece of code and my suggestion in the comment is wrong.